# Real Time Physics Based Mesh Deformation

Tags: unity

I'm working on a game through unity that draws one of is essential elements from traditional tool forging techniques for building tools and such. I want the feel of the game to be able to create a tool that is truly yours and slowly make it better in both design and functionality over time. One major thing I cant't seem to figure out is to be able to take a mesh (in this case a hot piece of meta) and deform it in such a way that you aren't loosing any of the mesh, its just being shifted slightly with each hit of a hammer (or in my testing case click of a mouse). I have looked all over youtube and various forums and I can't seem to find an efficient way of going about it. Any thoughts?

Comment: [We have some existing Q&A about how to procedurally deform a mesh without losing volume](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139274/39518), just "smushing it around." If you find the strategy described there doesn't work for you, or you need help solving a specific problem in making it work, please edit this question to describe the particular issue and we can re-open it for new answers.

Comment: [Please take the time to read our Code of Conduct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/conduct). We're all here to help each other succeed in making our games & mods. Name-calling and personal attacks are not acceptable uses of the site, and can result in suspension. If you feel you need additional information to help you along your way, simply edit your question to ask for it, clearly describing what specifically you need.

Comment: Mate rather than just shooting down posts try to help the auther out a bit by maybe, i dont know, **DIRECTING ME TO THE POSTS THAT SEEM TO "ALREADY EXIST"??** I dont ask questions on my account anymore because of the power hungry nature of half of you lot on this site that just down vote and shoot down posts instead of attempting to help

Comment: You should see a link to the existing duplicate Q&A post at the top of this page (just under the title of your question on the desktop website), and also in the link in my first comment above. I assure you, we are trying to help by linking you to this existing information. If these links are not displaying or working for you, then please let us know - there may be a bug that we need to escalate to the development team. I'll ask you to please be patient with fellow users here, and assume they are coming from a place of good faith - we're here volunteering our time to help each other, after all.

Comment: Everything I do on this site gets shot down by some power hungry pac-man that has nothing better to to than to kill of everything anyone else tries to do. No matter how much digging and research I do and no matter how many times I read over ever little guideline to make sure I fall within them its always just "Oops sucks to be you good luck finding what you need on your own"

Comment: You're not shut down. You asked for a strategy for.volume-preserving mesh deformation, and we linked you to one. If that's not meeting your needs, please edit your question to clarify what you need that's different, or where you're stuck putting that advice into practice. After you make those edits, we can re-open this question to get answers for that specific problem.